# Laravel - SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value

Tags: laravel

The following is the detailed error that I am getting. I am learning to make APIs with Laravel.

SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'false' for column `upwork_task`.`products`.`show` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `pro ducts` (`catalog_id`, `image`, `name`, `size`, `size_type`, `price`, `discounted_price`, `show`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, https://via.placehol
der.com/640x480.png/00bbdd?text=clothes+quam, iPhone 14 Pro Max, 3191, liter, 3981, 2910, false, 2022-09-20 21:36:02, 2022-09-20 21:36:02))

My migration file is as follows

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('catalog_id');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('size');
            $table->string('size_type');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->integer('discounted_price')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('show');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

My factory

```
public function definition()
    {
        $show = $this->faker->randomElement(['true', 'false']);
        $size_type = $this->faker->randomElement(['ml', 'liter', 'gm', 'kg', 'oz', 'lb']);
        $status = $this->faker->randomElement(['Y', 'N']); //Y means there is discount, N means there is none
        $price = $this->faker->numberBetween($min = 10, $max = 9999);

        return [
            'catalog_id' => Catalog::factory(),
            'image' => $this->faker->imageUrl($width = 640, $height = 480, 'clothes'),
            'name' => 'iPhone 14 Pro Max',
            'size' => $this->faker->numberBetween($min = 10, $max = 5000),
            'size_type' => $size_type,
            'price' => $price,
            'discounted_price' => $status == 'Y' ? $this->faker->numberBetween($min = $price * 0.6, $max = $price * 0.9) : null,
            'show' => $show,
        ];
    }
```

Comment: `'true'` and `'false'` are Strings, but you defined the `show` column as `->boolean()` (which is a `tinyint()`, which supports `0` and `1`). Did you maybe mean `$this->faker->randomElement([true, false])`, or `$this->faker->randomElement([1, 0])`?

Answer (score 0):

as per your migration file, the `show` column accepts a Boolean value, hence you need to change the following line from:

```
$show = $this->faker->randomElement(['true', 'false']);
```

to

```
$show = $this->faker->randomElement([true, false]);
```

where `'true'` is a string value, while `true` is Boolean.